# How can I draw the bottom spline if I use set_xlim and set_ylim in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot two sets of data, called **real_values** and **predicted_values**. The code I use is this:

```
def plot_experimental_vs_predicted_values(real_values, predicted_values, plot_title, show_plot=True):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(real_values) + 1)
    ax.set_ylim(min(chain(predicted_values, real_values)) * 0.95, max(chain(predicted_values, real_values)) * 1.05)
    ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
    ax.plot(range(1, len(real_values) + 1), real_values, '.', label='Experimental value')
    ax.plot(range(1, len(predicted_values) + 1), predicted_values, '.', label='Estimated value')
    plt.xlabel('Sample number')
    plt.ylabel('Experimental or estimated value')
    plt.legend()
    plt.title(plot_title)
    plt.xticks(range(0, len(real_values) + 1))
    plt.savefig('Full.png')
    if show_plot:
        plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

When call run the above function, I get the following graph: [image: graph:]

What can I do to display the bottom line? The X-axis?

Comment: You moved the spine far outside the plot (with `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')` ,at position 0 instead of at around 430).  What do you expect to happen? Do you want to scale down the plot to make 0 visible again?

Comment: I want to make the 0 and the horizontal axis visible again and the vertical axis to begin at 440.

Comment: You need to remove `ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`. Or set the ylim to `ax.set_ylim(ymin=0)` (this will scale down the plot a lot).

Comment: Worked. I removed the ``ax.spines['bottom']`` code. Thankies! You may write an answer if you want some rep points.